# I cannot log-in, in hangout when using Tor Browser

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, login

Normally I log-in my google plus page using the Tor Browser. However, I cannot use hangouts in google plus. It says "please sign in to chat with your friends". I have tried many times to sign in, but it always fails. Why?

Comment: What about script, flash, plugins in general?

Comment: Just in default.No plugins,allowed all script,no flash

Comment: At the momment I don't have a solution, but you could use pidgin or whatever and use xmpp server... for anonymity you can set tor as proxy... if for security reason you use 2FA you have to setup a dedicated password different from your master password...

Answer (score 1):

Use [pidgin](https://pidgin.im) and add your google account there. Should work great.