# Tor browser and Google hangouts

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, browsers, google, chat

I use tor browser for Gmail and Google+ account since April. It used to works good, but I have to switch on JavaScripts, of course. Gmail chat used to works good, but since today or yesterday Google changed chats to hangouts. I have to log to Google one time more for chats, but if I log in, chats still are not aviable (exit IP is the same like exit node to Gmail, and activity on Gmail shows log in from firefox and sometimes from mobile). I have heard too -  that Google talk (not only with Tor but normal too) do not work anymore. I have tried it with "Allow scripts globally" but it was with the same result.

I use Tor browser for windows, which was downloaded from torproject.org (with latest actualization).

I have find similar question, but in this time Google chat works good. It stop work today or yesterday.
[I cannot log-in, in hangout when using Tor Browser](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/6268/i-cannot-log-in-in-hangout-when-using-tor-browser)

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to do - if it doesn't compromise you in any way - is to check these things work without Tor.

The Google Talk client on Windows is no longer supported - it's **not** a problem with Tor.
"*As of February 2015, the Windows client ceased to work...*" (Wikipedia)

With regards to the old Google "Chat" interface in Gmail, this has moved over to Hangouts, as you've noticed. I don't believe there has been a changed in the protocols used underneath, so this should still work. (Also, if you want the original, old-style chat interface back, you can have it: http://www.fastcodesign.com/3047772/how-to-turn-off-google-hangouts-in-gmail).

Answer (score 1):

I know that is not problem in Tor browser, but something has changed in Google account. Many webs use Javascript, Flash, html5, third party cookies and other things, which are not secure or good for anonymity - these things are disabled by default in Tor Browser. If you want to use some web pages with this, you can enable them (e.g. cookies, Javascript) in the Tor browser settings.

For Google account - Javascript is necessary and for Hangouts - third party cookies are necessary. If you disable third party cookies, and log in to hangouts, it does not work. I have found this while exploring settings. Google Hangouts requires with Javascript and third party cookies. This is not so much ideal, but you can go only to Google account, and before and after visiting Google account, change settings and request a new identity in Tor Browser.

Comment: Welcome to the community. Thank you for the great answer! I edited you answer to help improve your answer.